# What is XYR in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I am familiar with XY, XYZ, and XYZM, features but I created a spatial layer in PostgreSQL and added it to my QGIS. When I opened the Vertex Editor it showed me values for XYR and I am not familiar with the R; can anyone tell me what it is? Is it the equivalent of ESRI's M value? 
I looked for a QGIS forum but their website directed me here.

Comment: What type of layer was it (point, line, polygon, etc.)? Perhaps this has something to do with curves?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It stands for "radius". It will only usually be populated for curved geoemtry types.

Comment: Well... that makes sense, thanks for straightening that out for me.